# Should i use a separate load balancer for my api and socket servers, or one with rules? (GCloud)

Tags: node.js, rest, socket.io, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I have been searching for an answer to this all morning as well as playing around with various setups but I am still not sure I have the right answer. (And I am new to this so appologies)

I have a node application on GCloud that has servers running a restful api, as well as servers running socket-io (linked by redis). The api communicates with the socket servers via redis and http calls (internally). I am using subdomains to distinguish each (api.* and socket.*)

I initially thought that each of these would be a service within one load balancer, and I would use rules to send traffic to the correct location. But the more I read, the more it seems as though using entirely separate balancers may be more appropriate, and save the services for things such as local considerations.

Any advise would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Having read a bunch of stuff about content based load balancing I feel this is what I am supposed to do. (such as doc bellow)
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example

When I try this, traffic works fine between client and socket, as i direct the traffic with a host rule. But when I try to make a call from my api server to the socket server (same VPC) i cannot distinguish it due to not having a host (tried using IP and it doesn't work)

I have managed to get it working with two separate load balancers but this does not seem to be what google expects and I wonder if it will cause me trouble (esp when I start to tackle https).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer this question as no one seems interested, but I warn you this is a hack. If anyone posts anything better I will bump it up accordingly.

In the end the only way the only way I could find to direct the calls from the api to the socket via the Load Balancer was to have the socket as the default (previously it was the api) and just let the traffic 'fall' through to it.

This is not ideal as if i had to do any other internal traffic to another server I wouldn't be able to, it will all just go to the socket service. It also means that any stray traffic to my domain will hit the socket servers.

For now it will have to do as I have spent way too much time on this already.